# error when I try to update virtual box guest addition: Running update file "/bin/sh" on guest failed: VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR 5

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualbox-guest-additions

My host is windows 11 and running linux on virtual machine. When I try to update my virtual box guest addition i get this error below.

```
Name: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso

Running update file "/bin/sh" on guest failed: VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR_5.
Result Code:
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0X80BB0005)
Component:
GuestSessionWrap
Interface:
IGuestSession {234f0627-866d-48c2-91a5-4c9d50f04928}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve the issue by installing the guest additions from within the guest system. The answer is largely based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm. I am attaching a how-to for the installation of Poseidon 9 in which the procedure is covered.

1. Install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable Package ( https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe, https://www.debugpoint.com/virtualbox-needs-microsoft-visual-c/)
2. Install the Oracle VM Virtual Box 7.0.8 (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
3. Download Poseidon 9 (https://sites.google.com/site/poseidonlinux/download)
4. Open the Virtual Box, create a new VM, select the ISO of Poseidon 9 for installation, install the Ubuntu version in the VM.
5. Restart the VM with Poseidon 9 and open up a terminal:

   - update the system: sudo apt-get update
   - upgrade the system: sudo apt-get upgrade
   - get the build-essential and dkms tools: sudo apt install build-essential dkms
   - get the guest additions from the repository (not the standard ones, they destroy everything): sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
   - make a new folder to mount the guest additions: sudo mkdir /mnt/iso
   - mount the iso file: sudo mount -o loop /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso /mnt/iso
   - go to the mounted iso file: cd /mnt/iso
   - install: sh autorun.sh (maybe sudo?)
   - unmount the iso: sudo umount /mnt/iso/
6. Close the terminal and shut off the VM
7. Go the the settings in the Virtual Box and add a shared folder
8. Start the VM. Most likely you do not have user rights to work in the shared folder yet. So, open a terminal

   - Install a command line editor: sudo apt install vim
   - Edit the /etc/group file
   - go to directory: cd /etc/
   - open in editor: sudo vim group
   - press "i" to go to edit mode, search for the line "vboxsf:x:999" (at the end most likely") and alternate to "vboxsf:x:999:username" (replace username with your ubuntu user name).
   - press "ESC" to leave edit mode, type ":wq" to write the changes and quit.
9. Log off and on again.
10. Do what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same error and solved by doing [the steps indicated here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1499828/1342430).

In particular, the "paragraph 3":

NOTE: your guest additions must be the same version as your virtualbox.

- in your VM: `cd /media/<MY_USER>/VBox_GAs_<VERSION_NUMBER>/`
- in your "mother OS": virtualbox "mother window" top bar > help > about virtualbox

> ### 3 - retrying installing Virtualbox Guest Additions
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> ```
>
> which returns no more warings, then
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
> ```
>
> then restart the VM via `sudo reboot`.
>
> Then, from the VirtualBox topbar "Device" menu -> Click "Insert guest
> additions CD" (it does not seem like it does anything, but it does
> indeed)
>
> finally
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom
> sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
> cd /mnt/cdrom
> sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
> ```
>
> go on when it asks if you want to install the guest additions even if
> they are already on the OS, and again restart the VM via `sudo reboot`.